# Cronjob not working Ubuntu Server

Tags: php, shell, ubuntu, cron

I just finished setting up a cronjob on my server. I created my `cron.sh`. If I run this file via SSH with `./cron.sh` everything its fine, its working as expected.

I added a new line within `/etc/crontab` file to run the `.sh at every 5 minutes` but its not working. I can't understand why.

Line added in crontab:

```
*/5 * * * * /var/www/sitename/wp-content/themes/themename/cron.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Its a Ubuntu Server. I guess i use a wrong crontab file.

I already set 777 fron cron.sh.

Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: Have you tried adding `/bin/sh` to call the script? `*/5 * * * * /bin/sh /var/www/sitename/wp-content/themes/themename/cron.sh ...`

Comment: remove the redirection to `/dev/null` and look at the errors. most probably it's an environment variable that is not set in the user the crontab is running under

Comment: Stan, as @GeraldSchneider suggests, remove `/dev/null` to see what's happenning. Or redirect to a file you can then check. Also, what I say is that you can use `*/5 * * * * /bin/sh /var/www/sitename/wp-content/themes/themename/cron.sh ...` instead of your current line. This will tell crontab which binary has to execute the script.

Comment: @fedorqui Will try now. I'll reply back within few minutes.

Comment: @Stan good, let us know what is the status.

Comment: Thank you guys.
I solved my problem.
I added in my crontab using "crontab -e":
`*/5 * * * * /bin/sh /var/www/sitename/wp-content/themes/themename/cron.sh > /var/www/sitename/wp-content/themes/themename/results.txt 2>&1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu prefers to use

> $ crontab -e

Instead of editing the file.

This will edit the crontab for the specific user you logged in as.

Comment: Thank you. The problem was solved: I added in my crontab using "crontab -e": `*/5 * * * * /bin/sh /var/www/sitename/wp-content/themes/themename/cron.sh > /var/www/sitename/wp-content/themes/themename/results.txt 2>&1`

Answer (score 0):

As [I see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20517224/cronjob-not-working-ubuntu-server#comment30679608_20517224) that it is what worked to you, I post [my initial comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20517224/cronjob-not-working-ubuntu-server#comment30672785_20517224) as an answer:

Have you tried adding `/bin/sh` to call the script?

```
*/5 * * * * /bin/sh /var/www/sitename/wp-content/themes/themename/cron.sh ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Something obscure that I just discovered this week, when manually editing `/etc/crontab`, you must have a newline character at the end, or apparently `crond` will ignore the line.  This was on an older FC10 box, however some quick Googling will show this is a known issue with `crontab`.

Answer (score 0):

if you edit /etc/crontab, you need to restart cond service
service crond restart

Answer (score 0):

First you can check already cron has scheduled or not.

```
crontab -l
```

After this if your cron is displaying there then just restart the cron service with below command.

```
service crond restart
```

If cron is not showing there then you should run.

```
crontab -e
```

then add your cron. after that just restart the cron service.

Please make sure at once if you previously edited cron file in any editor manually then there should not be any type of character type issue else cron will not working.